# Algorithm to compute a div d and a mod d

Tags: algorithms

I wanted to ask here a question about a simple algoirhtm to compute `a div d` and `a mod d`. My doubt specifically depend on negative numbers:

[image]

Doesn't the algorithm get wrong results for $-4$ and $2$ for instance, since the reminder of that division is 0? In this case the algorithm should give a quotient of $2$, But i image it should be $-2$, am i right?

Answer (score 2):

You're right. If this algorithm divides -k * d by d, it will return k as the result of the division instead of -k.

On top of that, if you divide one billion billions by one, it will take an eternity to finish. Execution time is O (|a| / d), which is just horribly bad.

Comment: (I think you want $\Omega(|a|/d)$ instead of $O(|a|/d)$).